# How does one read the syntax for the Braun tree insertion?

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching, agda, invariants

In the section on insertion into Braun trees of the [Verified Programming in Agda book](https://svn.divms.uiowa.edu/repos/clc/projects/agda/book/book.pdf) (page 118), the author does some explanation of what the code is supposed to be doing, but leaving what it does aside, a singificant ommision in the book so far is not explaining the strange syntax in function pattern matching for theorem proving.

I understand that the [with pattern](http://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language/with-abstraction.html) can be further destructured by using `|` and I can understand that when using `rewrite`, `|` can also be used to separate the different rewrites, but this makes it confusing.

As far as I can tell, rewrite is definitely not a function. And then comes the following:

```
bt-insert a (bt-node{n}{m} a' l r p) 
  rewrite +comm n m with p | if a <A a' then (a , a') else (a' , a)
bt-insert a (bt-node{n}{m} a' l r _) | inj₁ p | (a1 , a2) 
  rewrite p = (bt-node a1 (bt-insert a2 r) l (inj₂ refl))
bt-insert a (bt-node{n}{m} a' l r _) | inj₂ p | (a1 , a2) = 
  (bt-node a1 (bt-insert a2 r) l (inj₁ (sym p)))
```

I am really confused as to how `rewrite +comm n m with p | if a <A a' then (a , a') else (a' , a)` should be parsed mentally. And how does one read `| inj₁ p | (a1 , a2)  rewrite p`? Also, while testing the previous examples I've discovered that for some reason the order of the rewrites does not matter. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

If you ignore the proofs for a sec, this function can be simplified as

```
bt-insert :  ∀ {n: ℕ} → A → braun-tree n → braun-tree (suc n)
bt-insert a (bt-node {n} {m} a' l r _) = bt-node a1 (bt-insert a2 r) l _
  where 
    (a1, a2) = if a <A a' then (a , a') else (a' , a)
```

So `(a1, a2)` is just `(min a a', max a a')`  i.e. `(a, a')` sorted.

All the other code is there to maintain the proofs of the invariants:

- We `rewrite +comm n m` so that we can return a `braun-tree (2 + (m + n))` even though the return type requires a `braun-tree (2 + (n + m))`.
- `p` is used to prove that the resulting tree is still balanced: `p` proves that `n ≡ m ∨ n ≡ suc m`, so it's either `inj₁ (p : n ≡ m)` or `inj₂ (p : n ≡ suc m)`. We use the proof of either property to compute the proof of `suc m ≡ n ∨ suc m ≡ suc n` (remember we flipped `n` and `m` via the proof of commutativity).

Answer (score 0):

After pondering it for a bit, I realized that if...

```
              p | if a <A a' then (a , a') else (a' , a)
         inj₁ p | (a1 , a2)
```

I put the expressions like that then it makes sense visually. In bt_insert's second case the rewrite comes before the if statement and in the third case it comes after the destructuring of the if pattern.

Well, that leaves figuring out what the rest of the function is doing.